# Google Analytics Reporting Api "Unable to parse the p12 file. Is this a .p12 file?"

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I cant seem to fined an updated tutorial for getting the .p12 file from the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("XXXXXXXX");
$client->setAssertionCredentials(
         new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
              'xxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
              array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
             file_get_contents(app_path()."\config\analytics\client_secret_xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json")
            )
        );
$client->setClientId('xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setAccessType('offline_access');

$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```

Im getting this error

```
Unable to parse the p12 file. Is this a .p12 file? Is the password correct? OpenSSL error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
```

Im using the latest version of the api at [repository](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). 
The file im trying to parce is the one downloaded in the developer console under: Apis & Auth -> credentials -> Download JSON. Right after creating a new Cliend Id. I cant fined were the .p12 file can be downloaded or if it still necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `Service Account` not a `Web Application` or `Installed Application`. Once you've created such a client there's a button called "Generate new P12 key" that you can use to generate and download a .p12 file.